# Jenkins custom build parameter statistics

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a Jenkins free style job which take some parameters

1. RICEFW( Basically the name of the file which need to be deployed)
2. Server name
3. Environment
4. SVN branch

the RICEFWs are different files in SVN which are getting deployed and dev can give different RICEFWs or Same RICEFWs(They will update the file and do SVN check in) multiple time .

**My requirement is to Show a graph which states what are the different RICEFWs were deployed for the Job in a Day**.

Have checked build statistics plugin and Text-filter plugin (as the RICEFWs info comes in jenkins console) but nothing seems to fulfill my requirement